# simple fix regex validation for phone number

Tags: php, regex

i have this one so far used for validation a phone number in my form:

`/^\s*\+?\s*([0-9]+\s*)+\s*(\((\+?[0-9]+\s*)+\))?\s*[0-9-\s]*[0-9]\s*$/`

it works for like those numbers : `+021 (+12) 113-2145` but i need to add an extension to the end of it like this : `+021 (+12) 113-2145 x 123` so how can i add the char `x` and after that the digits?

also the spaces between the `x` and digits should be optional like in my code above.

any idea? thanks!

Comment: It seems like you understand regular expressions pretty well. Why don't you just add the `x` and extension number to your regex?

Comment: i tried in many ways but not working so maybe i'm missing something :) need a bit of help with this. thanks!

Comment: yes this is an optional thing

Comment: And do you need backreferences in your regex for the extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you could replace all instances of `[0-9]` with the shorter `\d`. (for decimal digit)

Then, add this to the original regex:

```
(x\s*[\d]{3})?
```

So it would be

```
/^\s*\+?\s*([\d]+\s*)+\s*(\((\+?[\d]+\s*)+\))?\s*[\d-\s]*[\d]\s*(x\s*[\d]{3})?$/
```

**Edit:** Made the extension optional

**Edit 2:** Used `\d` instead of `[0-9]`

Comment: didn't work also :( the format should be `+021 (+12) 113-2145 x 123` or `+021 (+12) 113-2145 x123` or `+021 (+12) 113-2145x 123` or `+021 (+12) 113-2145x123` like this . thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
/^\s*\+?\s*([0-9]+\s*)+\s*(\((\+?[0-9]+\s*)+\))?\s*[0-9-\s]*[0-9]\s*(x\s*[0-9]+)?$/;
```

Added: (x\s*[0-9]+)?;
Edit:

```
$pattern = '/^\s*\+?\s*([0-9]+\s*)+\s*(\((\+?[0-9]+\s*)+\))?\s*[0-9-\s]*[0-9]\s*(x\s*[0-9]+)?$/';
$subject = '+021 (+12) 113-2145 x 123';
if(preg_match($pattern, $subject))
    echo 'matched';
```